# Возможно ли через SQL запрос открыть внешнее подключение к базе сайта

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, хостинг

Нужно подключится к базе данных MySQL на хостинге сайта через SSMS manager studio.
По всей видимости база закрыта для внешних подключений, поскольку дает подключится лишь напрямую с хостинга через PHPMyadmin.

Есть возможность отправлять SQL запрос

Можно ли открыть внешнее подключения через  SQL запрос?

Comment: Да можно. Вам потребуется открыть порт 3306  или какой у вашего сервера Mysql, и создать в БД пользователя с удаленным доступом.
Сам по себе хостинг вам выдает данные для подключения и они по идее уже настроены на удаленный доступ.

Comment: Возьмите ip адрес из ссылки phpmyadmin и попробуйте пропинговать на своем пк с портами 3306 3307 если ответ получите то проблем нет. Только я не уверен в SSMS manager studio, попробуйте Workbench

Comment: это я знаю, проблема в том что сервер дает подключиться только с хоста, если я выхожу и пытаюсь сам войти в phpmyadmin? то подключение не удаётся, также и с studio

Comment: вот и появилась идея забить на безопасность и открыть все подключения, есть подозрение на блокировку внешних подключений

Comment: Вы можете базу mysql разместить не на хостинге? Тогда сам сайт можно было бы оставить на хосте но без базы.

Comment: а вообще странный хостинг. Не подскажете название?

Comment: timeweb , или я что-то желаю не так

Comment: Цель этого гемороя возможность в дальнейшем подключиться программно в приложении на c#. нужно крупный объем однообразных данных с генерировать и залить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае вам нужно сделать "проброс" (другое название - туннель/туннелирование) порта MySQL-сервера через ssh-соединение с вашего компьютера. 
Обычно если вы используете не панель админки shared-хостинга, а shell (cli), т.е. ssh-подключение выделенного (dedicated) сервера - у вас есть такая возможность.
Обычно [я делаю это в программе HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/help.php#connecting), вот картинка:
[image: настройка ssh(plink) туннеля в HeidiSQL]
http://www.sternkn.com/ssh-tunnel-in-heidisql/

При возникновении ошибки [загуглите её текст на форуме программы](http://google.ru/search?q=plink.exe%20-L%20%20:localhost:%20%20mysql%20tunneling%20site:www.heidisql.com)

У ORACLE (владельцы MySQL) есть "родной" клиент для работы с mysql-базами - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Для подключения к базе MySQL с помощью **именно** SQL Server **Management** Studio (SSMS) на серверной стороне нужно будет установить драйвер доступа (Connector) к БД [mysql-connector-odbc](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) подходящей разрядности (x86 или x64)

и настроить подключение к источнику данных - DSN
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Если вам привычнее (или уже имеются лицензии, позволяющие использовать MS**SQLServer** - можете перенести на него свою MySQL-базу при помощи [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA)][5]

Существуют и другие способы доступа к данным из приложения, например [Link Server][6], но там свои [проблемы и неудобства, например, со скоростью][7]

Comment: Пытался написать подробно, но движок не дал вставить все ссылки:   [5]: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/installing-ssma-for-mysql-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-2017
  [6]: https://superuser.com/questions/163610/anyway-to-use-ssms-to-connect-to-mysql
  [7]: https://habr.com/en/post/302958/